# How to auto-generate primary key constraint using hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have to run an initialization sql skript that creates a table with a specific tablespace as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table() TABLESPACE my_table_space;
```

Now I want `hibernate` to auto generate the table schema accordingly to an entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
}
```

with `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`.

Result: the table is created **without** the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint. Why? How can I enforce this?

Comment: Add the constrain in the initialization sql script. 

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto doesn't always work as expected. For example it doesn't change data types of existing columns, doesnt add constrains etc. It is always better to create the table the way you want

Comment: Which database are you using? Are you using the JPA-Interface or the Hibernate-Interface to access Hibernate?

Comment: I'm using postgresql 9.4

Comment: Try to add `@Table(name = "my_table")` annotation to the class definition. Because in your case hibernate is looking for table named `MyEntity` instead of `my_table`, If I’m not mistaken.

Comment: You're right, to make this work proberly this would be required. Anyhow this is just an example to demonstrate my problem, or course hibernate finds the correct table in my local code.

Comment: Check if you've been using correct dialect, in your case `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`. Anyway would be better if you provide more information about your configuration.

Comment: I'm using the right dialect. My configuration above is nearly complete. I'm using it in context of `spring-boot`, but that does not matter.

Comment: Have a look into [spring-boot reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases) in your case should be `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: Of course I have set this. I just wrote in my **example** above the usually known hibernate property, as not everybody is familiar with spring-boot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76623/discussion-between-peter-jurkovic-and-membersound).